# Association class SQLite tables and foreign keys

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, associations

If I had an association table between two many-to-many table would the tables look as follows?:

Practical:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_PRACTICAL =
    "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRACTICAL  + "(" +
        Practical_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY," +
        Start_Date + " DATE," +
        End_Date + " DATE," +
        Practical_Type + " STRING," +
        Practical_Topic + " STRING" +
    ");";
```

Module:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MODULE =
    "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MODULE + "(" +
        Module_Code + " STRING NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY," +
        Module_Name + " STRING," +
        Year_Level + " INTEGER," +
        Lecturer_Name + " STRING," +
        Lecturer_Email + " STRING" +
    ");";
```

ModulePrac:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_PRAC_MODULES =
    "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRAC_MODULES + "(" +
        Practical_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
        Module_Code + "STRING NOT NULL," +
        " FOREIGN KEY " + "(" + Practical_ID + ")" +
            "REFERENCES" + TABLE_PRACTICAL + "(" + Practical_ID + ")" +
        " FOREIGN KEY " + "(" + Module_Code + ")" +
            "REFERENCES" + TABLE_MODULE + "(" + Module_Code + ")" +
    ");";
```

Or should the PracModule table's key identifiers be:

```
Practical_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Practicals(PracticalID),
ModuleCode INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Module (ModuleCode),
PRIMARY KEY (PracticalID, ModuleCode)
```

Different sites say that both the primary keys for the tables are foreign keys for the association class while others say they are both the foreign key and primary key. I'm very confused by that.

Comment: `CREATE_TABLE_PRAC_MODULES` has a typo: the comma between the two FOREIGN KEY constraints is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you write these foreign key constraints as table constraints (as in `CREATE_TABLE_PRAC_MODULES`) or as column constraints (as in your last code block) does not make any difference.
(It's usually simpler to write them as column constraints, but a table constraint is needed if a foreign key consists of multiple columns.)

The only real difference is that the second code block declares the primary key.

There's nothing wrong with a primary key that is also (entirely or partially) a foreign key, as long as this correctly describes the actual relationships between your entities.
In this case, this appears to be correct.